# TypeError: mel() takes 0 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python

When I was on the Tacotron Training Notebook, I got an error message saying this.`Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-10-df8aeedb909f> in <module> 2  3 if generate_mels: ----> 4     create_mels()` `TypeError: mel() takes 0 positional arguments but 5 were given.` Can somebody give me a solution?

I tried adding self to create mels, but that failed. Update: I copied the full code from the convert WAVS to Mel Spectrograms section.

```
def create_mels():
    print("Generating Mels")
    stft = layers.TacotronSTFT(
                hparams.filter_length, hparams.hop_length, hparams.win_length,
                hparams.n_mel_channels, hparams.sampling_rate, hparams.mel_fmin,
                hparams.mel_fmax)
    def save_mel(filename):
        audio, sampling_rate = load_wav_to_torch(filename)
        if sampling_rate != stft.sampling_rate:
            raise ValueError("{} {} SR doesn't match target {} SR".format(filename, 
                sampling_rate, stft.sampling_rate))
        audio_norm = audio / hparams.max_wav_value
        audio_norm = audio_norm.unsqueeze(0)
        audio_norm = torch.autograd.Variable(audio_norm, requires_grad=False)
        melspec = stft.mel_spectrogram(audio_norm)
        melspec = torch.squeeze(melspec, 0).cpu().numpy()
        np.save(filename.replace('.wav', ''), melspec).
```

Is this not enough info?

Comment: And what's your code?

Comment: if generate_mels:
    create_mels(). That's all I know.

Comment: This is not enough information. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part about creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: We need to know how  and where `mel`() gets called

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 7):

I downloaded another version of librosa and it's working for me now.
It gives an error because the newest version 0.10.? is not taking arguments anymore.
`pip install "librosa=0.9.1"`

Comment: Your post does not appear to relate to the question at all. Did you mean to post this somewhere else?

Comment: it solved the problem "TypeError: mel() takes 0 positional arguments but 5 were given." for me

Comment: This then prints:

src/naturalspeech/utils/mel_processing.py:117: FutureWarning: Pass sr=22050, n_fft=1024, n_mels=80, fmin=0.0, fmax=None as keyword args. From version 0.10 passing these as positional arguments will result in an error

Comment: @GardnerBickford This is only a warning which announces the error will be thrown  in version 0.10. That means that Fuchun Hsieh's answer is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Update your call to mel() to include argument names:

e.g.
`mel = librosa_mel_fn(sr=sampling_rate, n_fft=n_fft, n_mels=num_mels, fmin=fmin, fmax=fmax)`

instead of:
`mel = librosa_mel_fn(sampling_rate, n_fft, num_mels,  fmin, fmax)`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to:
melspec = stft.mel_spectrogram(y=audio_norm).
it works for me.

This seems to occur due to changes made in the new librosa version (0.10), as they seem to have changed a positional argument to a keyword argument for the input of this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
melspec = stft.mel_spectrogram(audio_norm)
```

has to be

```
melspec = stft.mel_spectrogram(y=audio_norm)
```

Comment: Adding a little explanation as to how this addresses the question would greatly improve this answer.