# Google Colab using the latest version of a file for stacktracing but not for running code

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am new to Colab and want to test [MakeItTalk](https://github.com/yzhou359/MakeItTalk). I open the Colab notebook, fix one bug in the cell below "Step 2" (`face_alignment.LandmarksType._3D` is now `face_alignment.LandmarksType.THREE_D`, [reference](https://github.com/yzhou359/MakeItTalk/issues/93)), and run it until the cell below "Step 3", where I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-50fe2f4fa52c> in <cell line: 6>()
     16     c = AutoVC_mel_Convertor('examples')
     17 
---> 18     au_data_i = c.convert_single_wav_to_autovc_input(audio_filename=os.path.join('examples', ain),
     19            autovc_model_path=opt_parser.load_AUTOVC_name)
     20     au_data += au_data_i

1 frames
/content/MakeItTalk/src/autovc/retrain_version/vocoder_spec/extract_f0_func.py in extract_f0_func_audiofile(audio_file, gender)
     95 def extract_f0_func_audiofile(audio_file, gender='M'):
     96     floor_sp, ceil_sp = -80, 30
---> 97     mel_basis = mel(16000, 1024, fmin=90, fmax=7600, n_mels=80).T
     98     min_level = np.exp(-100 / 20 * np.log(10))
     99     b, a = butter_highpass(30, 16000, order=5)

TypeError: mel() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 positional arguments (and 3 keyword-only arguments) were given
```

The `mel` function in `librosa` indeed changed to 0 positional arguments ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75796284/typeerror-mel-takes-0-positional-arguments-but-5-were-given)), so I click on the offending file and edit the source code to have only keyword arguments:

```
def extract_f0_func_audiofile(audio_file, gender='M'):
    floor_sp, ceil_sp = -80, 30
    mel_basis = mel(sr=16000, n_fft=1024, fmin=90, fmax=7600, n_mels=80).T
```

I save the source code (I had to make a copy of the notebook to be able to save) and run it again. And I get the same error, even though the stack trace shows my version of the source code.

I comment that line and place an assertion before, and I still get the same error:

```
/content/MakeItTalk/src/autovc/retrain_version/vocoder_spec/extract_f0_func.py in extract_f0_func_audiofile(audio_file, gender)
     95 def extract_f0_func_audiofile(audio_file, gender='M'):
     96     floor_sp, ceil_sp = -80, 30
---> 97     assert False
     98     #mel_basis = mel(sr=16000, n_fft=1024, fmin=90, fmax=7600, n_mels=80).T
     99     min_level = np.exp(-100 / 20 * np.log(10))

TypeError: mel() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 positional arguments (and 3 keyword-only arguments) were given
```

So Colab is using the latest version of the file for showing the error but not for running the code. How can I force it to run the new version of the file?